# Firebase/Node/React How to copy files from one firebase project to another?

Tags: firebase, firebase-storage, google-cloud-firestore

I have a two Firebase projects using Storage to store files and Firestore for metadata. One project is for Staging and the other is for Production. I have a simple react app setup for uploading my files and metadata to the Staging project.

I'm trying to figure out how to sync the Staging Storage and Firestores to the Production project. I haven't had much luck with google searches or the Firebase documentation (beyond seeing that you can connect to multiple firebase projects using node).

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Currently, for Firestore, you will have to write your own code that queries for the documents you want to copy, then adds them to the other database.  There is no import/export functionality you can use to make this easier. The Firestore team is working on making this easier in the future.

For Cloud Storage, there is a command line utility called [gsutil](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil) that makes copying files to and from storage buckets easier.

Comment: Thanks. I was able to setup syncing between firestore databases pretty easily. Is there no way to sync Cloud Storage using an API? I need to make a webinterface for triggering the syncing rather then using a command line utility.

Comment: Nothing automatic that I know of.  You could write code for that as well using a Cloud Storage SDK.